# Merge Statement on Duplicate Leads/Contacts

Tags: apex, duplicate-management

We currently have a web form that connects to leads in Salesforce - The issue with this is that we are finding that we have contacts with the same email address/similar names.

It is possible in apex to use the merge method on leads and contacts in the same DML?

Ex

```
Merge contact Lead
```

Comment: Why you are not using the [Contacts-Leads](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=matching_rules_standard_contact_rule.htm&type=5) standard matching rules? That should take care of the duplicate / merge problem for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. To convert a lead to a contact, use the [Database.convertLead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#!) method.

Comment: Should I convert the lead and then use the merge method?

Comment: @MatthewMetros You can convert directly to the existing contact, no merge call is required.

Comment: Does it do this based on the email? I am assuming, but just checking

Comment: @MatthewMetros The logic in Apex is left up to you. You can perform whatever type of matching algorithm you'd like.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question - I am looking to see if we can merge leads and contacts using the merge statement in apex. If we cannot do this, should I first convert the leads and then merge them from there using whatever logic?

Comment: @MatthewMetros I'm using specific terminology. The "merge" operation is specific to merging two or more leads with each other, contacts with each other, and accounts with each other. All records in the merge must be of the same type. The "convert lead" function, in contrast, allows a lead to be merged in to an existing account and contact simultaneously, while optionally creating an Opportunity as well. It basically means the same thing, but each has a specific nomenclature.